# IN clause not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `dt_prdtime` (
  `TCompany` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TPerCode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `TBegDateTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'วันที่',
  `TQPay` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `TYear` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `TMonth` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TCompany`,`TPerCode`,`TBegDateTime`),
  KEY `TMonth` (`TMonth`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `TPerCode` (`TPerCode`,`TYear`,`TMonth`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this is data sample. This table has 10000+ records and value in `TMonth` field varies

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+--------+
| TCompany | TPerCode | TBegDateTime        | TQPay | TYear | TMonth |
+----------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+--------+
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-02 17:33:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-02 07:48:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-03 17:39:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-03 07:30:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-04 17:49:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-04 07:54:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-05 17:50:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-05 07:36:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-06 17:37:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
| S10      | 000001   | 2016-01-06 07:35:00 |     1 |  2016 |      1 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+-------+-------+--------+
```

With `EXPLAIN`, This query uses `TMonth` index:

```
SELECT * FROM dt_prdtime WHERE TMonth = 5
```

while this one refuses to use the index:

```
SELECT * FROM dt_prdtime WHERE TMonth IN (5,6)
```

I tested with another simple table,

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id IN (5,6)
```

and the index for this table was used

Can anybody explain this? Is there something wrong with `dt_prdtime` table?

Comment: This might be due to the optimizer. Sometimes optimizer estimates not use an index, even if one is available. Have you tried FORCE index?

Comment: SELECT * FROM dt_prdtime FORCE INDEX (`TMonth`) WHERE TMonth IN (5, 6)

Comment: You shouldn't have to force an index. That is a good time to pack your bags and not use that rdbms

Comment: agree, because we have to believe optimizer has a point if not using index

Comment: Are you deliberately ignoring the year when asking about May?  If not, there is a better way to do your task, even for (5,6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go out on a limb and say it is because you are using the MyISAM engine.

It is working perfectly fine with INNODB as can be seen in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002986) of mine.

I will try to spook up at least 1 honorable reference on the matter.

Here, [The range Join Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-range-join-type.html), clearly an INNODB focus as it is the default engine. And when not explicitly mentioned in the manual in some documentation hierarchy, it is assumed.

Note, there is nothing contiguous about the id's in my example link. Meaning, don't hyperfocus on `type=range` in its EXPLAIN output. The speed is arrived at via the Optimizer (the CBO).

The `cardinality` in my example is very high (4.3 Million). The target id counts are relatively low (1000). The index is used.

Your situation may be the opposite: your cardinality might be incredibly low, like 3, and the optimizer decides to abandon use of the index.

To check your index `cardinality`, see the Manual Page [SHOW INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html).

A simple call such as:

```
show index from ratings;

+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| ratings |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     4313544 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Does this means I have to change the table to InnoDB? I don't see any changes in EXPLAIN at all.

Comment: You need volume. Ignore explain for small tables (as it relates to the reality when it grows). Let me do an edit to this comment in 1 minute with a url. Edit: read this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38108599) .

Comment: So from what I understand, it doesn't exploit the index because the table is very large and this query needs to process all rows?

Comment: If that is your reality then correct. If the target count  is sparse in quantity and the table is huge and the index is in good health (statistics / analyze) it uses it. If it has to use the lion-share of a huge table it won't use it. If the table has 20 rows it won't use it.

Comment: If it determines through low `cardinality` that it makes no sense, it may abandon the use of it. [Show Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html) shows cardinality. My example has extremely high cardinality, and sparse targets. It is more than happy to use my index.

Comment: I get it. I tried indexing TPerCode field which has higher cardinality and selected it, it uses the index. Can I mark this as an answer?

Comment: Works for me. I can tweak my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither MyISAM, nor InnoDB, is likely to use an index when "too much" of the table needs to be fetched.

`IN (5,6)` may mean 2/12ths of the table needs to be scanned?  Or maybe the data is biased such that those two months have more than their share of rows?

The reason the optimizer *might* eschew the index in cases like this...

When using such an index, it needs to spend a lot of time bouncing between the index (one BTree) and the data.

When not using the index, it simply cruises through the data, ignoring 10/12ths of the rows.  This *may* actually be faster.

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM dt_prdtime WHERE TMonth = 5` uses the index, why `IN (5,6)` doesn't? It's practically the same, just one more number than `TMonth = 5` to find. How is it different? Why does it scan the whole table when it's a lot faster to find these numbers in the index?

Comment: The cutoff is not exact.  Often it is around 20%. One month is 8% (if evenly distributed); two months is 17%.  Perhaps the statistics decided to cutoff below 17% in your case.  Let's carry it farther, does it make sense for `IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11)`?